# How can I append to an existing java.io.ObjectStream?

Tags: java, serialization, append, objectinputstream

As for now I will get `java.io.StreamCorruptedException` when I try to append an Object. I have searched the Internet for a way to overcome that. The answer I found so far is it can't be done. A way around this problem is to write the objects into a list and then write the list to the file.

But I have to overwrite that file everytime when I add new objects. It seems not to be the optimal solution in overtime.

Is there a way to append objects to an existing object stream?

Comment: Is it possible for you to use a database for persistence?

Comment: @danben: yea, the question is if objects can be appended to a file.
@Asaph: I could do that, but I want to know if append is no for objects. Sry if my question didn't clarify that.

Comment: Is that `ObjectOutputStream` ?

Comment: @Oscar: yes, ObjectInputStream, and ObjectOutputStream

Comment: ... And how are you appending the object?

Comment: @Oscar: using the writeObject() method which is found in ObjectOutputStream

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is actually pretty easy to do. When you are adding to an existing stream you need to use a subclass of ObjectOutStream that overrides `writeStreamHeader` so that a second header is not written in the middle of the file. For example

```
class NoHeaderObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream {
  public NoHeaderObjectOutputStream(OutputStream os) {
    super(os);
  }
  protected void writeStreamHeader() {}
}
```

Then just use a standard ObjectInputStream to read the whole file.

Comment: Very nice, void write(byte[] b, int off, int len, boolean copy) uses unfortunatly private method writeBlockHeader.

Comment: +1 I read that in the documentation but ( as it often happens me with documentation ) I didn't quite get it, until now.

Comment: @stacker I don't see how that causes any problem. That header is part of the format of the serialized stream to say read the next n bytes as a single byte array and will be read properly when consuming the stream later.

Comment: Excellent tip, Geoff.  Once again, SO makes me aware of a new technique

Answer (score 5):

The best article I've found on this topic is: 
http://codify.flansite.com/2009/11/java-serialization-appending-objects-to-an-existing-file/

The "solution" that overrides ObjectOutputStream is simply wrong. I've just finished investigating a bug that was caused by that (wasting two precious days). Not only that it would sometimes corrupt the serialized file but even managed to read without throwing exceptions and in the end providing garbage data (mixing fields). For those in disbelief, I'm attaching some code that exposes the problem:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File storageFile = new File("test");
        storageFile.delete();

        write(storageFile, getO1());
        write(storageFile, getO2());
        write(storageFile, getO2());

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(storageFile));
        read(ois, getO1());
        read(ois, getO2());
        read(ois, getO2());
    }

    private static void write(File storageFile, Map<String, String> o) throws IOException {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = getOOS(storageFile);
        oos.writeObject(o);
        oos.close();
    }

    private static void read(ObjectInputStream ois, Map<String, String> expected) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        Object actual = ois.readObject();
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

    private static void assertEquals(Object o1, Object o2) {
        if (!o1.equals(o2)) {
            throw new AssertionError("\n expected: " + o1 + "\n actual:   " + o2);
        }
    }

    private static Map<String, String> getO1() {
        Map<String, String> nvps = new HashMap<String, String>();
        nvps.put("timestamp", "1326382770000");
        nvps.put("length", "246");
        return nvps;
    }

    private static Map<String, String> getO2() {
        Map<String, String> nvps = new HashMap<String, String>();
        nvps.put("timestamp", "0");
        nvps.put("length", "0");
        return nvps;
    }

    private static ObjectOutputStream getOOS(File storageFile) throws IOException {
        if (storageFile.exists()) {
            // this is a workaround so that we can append objects to an existing file
            return new AppendableObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(storageFile, true));
        } else {
            return new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(storageFile));
        }
    }

    private static class AppendableObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream {

        public AppendableObjectOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
            super(out);
        }

        @Override
        protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {
            // do not write a header
        }
    }
}
```

As stated in that article, you can use one of the following solutions:

> **Solution #1: Fake Multiple file in a Single Stream**
>
> ...
>
> Write your “transaction” to a ByteArrayOutputStream, then write the
>   length and contents of this ByteArrayOutputStream to a file via the
>   DataOutputStream.
>
> **Solution #2:  Reopen and Skip**
>
> Another solution involves saving the file position using:
>
> ```
> long pos = fis.getChannel().position();
> ```
>
> closing the file, reopening the file, and skipping to this position
>   before reading the next transaction.

Comment: Here are a pair of functions (in Scala) that implement Solution #1

Answer (score 3):

Many thanks to *George Hategan* for the problem exposing code. I examined it for a while too. Then, it hit me. If you're using a sub-classed ***ObjectOutputStream*** with an override of the ***writeStreamHeader()*** method to write data, you must use the parallel sub-classed ***ObjectInputStream*** with an override of the ***readStreamHeader()*** method to read the data. Of course, we can zig-zag between different implementations of writing and reading objects, but as long as we use the corresponding pairs of sub-classes in the write/read process - we'll be (hopefully) fine. Tom.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SerializationDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File storageFile = new File("test.ser");
        storageFile.delete();
        write(storageFile, getO1());
        write(storageFile, getO2());
        write(storageFile, getO2());
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(storageFile);
        read(fis, getO1());
        read(fis, getO2());
        read(fis, getO2());
        fis.close();
    }

    private static void write(File storageFile, Map<String, String> o)
                    throws IOException {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = getOOS(storageFile);
        oos.writeObject(o);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
    }

    private static void read(FileInputStream fis, Map<String, String> expected)
                    throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        Object actual = getOIS(fis).readObject();
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
        System.out.println("read serialized " + actual);
    }

    private static void assertEquals(Object o1, Object o2) {
        if (!o1.equals(o2)) {
            throw new AssertionError("\n expected: " + o1 + "\n actual:   " + o2);
        }
    }

    private static Map<String, String> getO1() {
        Map<String, String> nvps = new HashMap<String, String>();
        nvps.put("timestamp", "1326382770000");
        nvps.put("length", "246");
        return nvps;
    }

    private static Map<String, String> getO2() {
        Map<String, String> nvps = new HashMap<String, String>();
        nvps.put("timestamp", "0");
        nvps.put("length", "0");
        return nvps;
    }

    private static ObjectOutputStream getOOS(File storageFile)
                    throws IOException {
        if (storageFile.exists()) {
            // this is a workaround so that we can append objects to an existing file
            return new AppendableObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(storageFile, true));
        } else {
            return new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(storageFile));
        }
    }

    private static ObjectInputStream getOIS(FileInputStream fis)
                    throws IOException {
        long pos = fis.getChannel().position();
        return pos == 0 ? new ObjectInputStream(fis) : 
            new AppendableObjectInputStream(fis);
    }

    private static class AppendableObjectOutputStream extends
                    ObjectOutputStream {

        public AppendableObjectOutputStream(OutputStream out)
                        throws IOException {
            super(out);
        }

        @Override
        protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {
            // do not write a header
        }
    }

    private static class AppendableObjectInputStream extends ObjectInputStream {

        public AppendableObjectInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
            super(in);
        }

        @Override
        protected void readStreamHeader() throws IOException {
            // do not read a header
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a new `ObjectInputStream` to match every `ObjectOutputStream`. I don't know a way to transfer state from a complete `ObjectInputStream` to an `ObjectOutputStream` (without a complete reimplementation, which is a bit tricky in pure Java anyway).